# What is the "Peer Pressure" Badge?

Tags: support, badges, peer-pressure-badge

I have earned the **Peer Pressure Badge** on my question on Stack Overflow. The question title is, "Setup And Deployment By Reading Bios Of User System". I don't know why I earned this badge; is there something wrong with my question? Did I do anything wrong with peers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure) page:

> Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower.

Comment: That means whenever my question reach -3 or lower and deleted the same will received this badge every time?.

Comment: @mahesh no, I think this badge gets awarded only the first time