# Is it bad form to answer a question with a rhetorical question?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

Today I noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991919/1327774) to a question is in the form of a questions.  Now professors/teachers use this technique all the time to encourage the student to think a little more instead of spoon feeding the answer.  But is this appropriate for the FAQ format of Stack Exchange?

Comment: Duplicate? [Should the “Socratic method” be discouraged?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177612/145673)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It does address directly the question that the OP asked.

I do see, however, that it went nowhere; the OP states in a comment below the answer that he already understands the problem, even though he asks in his question why the error is occurring.  This is the most common outcome that I see from rhetorical questions posted as answers.

For that reason, it's probably better as a comment.  As the OP points out, the answer is restating the problem, not offering a solution.

Comment: Do you believe that this extends to the general case for all answers?

Comment: Yes.  Rhetorical questions in answers work better if you subsequently explain why you are asking them.

Comment: Since I'm the one who started this by writing that answer let me explain my thought process.  Based on what the user originally asked it was not clear to me that the OP fully understood the problem.  Now that the question has been clarified I have updated my answer and provided more information.

Answer (score 14):

Why would someone do such a thing?!?

Comment: Indeed meta is different.

Comment: I see what you did there, but I'm not sure this is adequately illustrative.  On the main site, this kind of answer would get removed within minutes.

Comment: Understood. Couldn't pass it up.

Comment: Just what I was about to do.

Comment: "On the main site, this kind of answer would get removed within minutes" by using the "not an answer" flag :D (*innocent whistle*)

Comment: "To flag or not to flag?"

Answer (score 6):

I do this quite a bit, but usually in the form of a comment. After all, the Answers section of a post is supposed to include *answers*, not questions (rhetorical or not).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
What should be done:
 - Flag with a custom explanation, and explain why you feel the answer is actively harmful and merits removal

While a debate <strike>is</strike> was in place in this question that the "not an answer" flag should be used, the official stance is this flag is intended for things like *"I have the same problem..."*, *"Thanks, this is a great"*, and not just any definition that you see as "not an answer" or "did not attempt to answer the question".

Although it should be noted that, depending on severity of the answer's quality, often downvote and a comment might be the right course of action. This provides the answerer chance to come and correct their answer once they're aware of it.
In fact in this particular instance the answerer did just that, and avoided losing a [possibly] decent answer!

---

The following was/is my opinion, and not actually what should be done (I've left it as it's the basis of the large discussion following this answer):

> It's not an answer, it's a question.
>
> It's a question, and therefore "not an answer", given the fact the 1st sentence "does not answer or attempt to answer the question", and the 2nd sentence starts with "What happens if" and ends in a question mark.
>
> Flag it as "not an answer" and (imo) downvote it so it goes beneath other possibly better answers (or at least *actual* answers) until it's removed. Downvote also signals to the answerer to improve this and possibly their future answers.

---

Comment: Be cautious with "Not an Answer" flags; they are intended for things like "I have the same problem, does anyone have a solution," and "Thanks, this is a great post."  With answers like the one being discussed here, it is better to flag with a custom explanation, and explain why you feel the answer is actively harmful and merits removal.

Comment: Well, I see it as a question, and therefore "not an answer" (as per the perfect flag of the same words), given the fact the sentence starts with "What happens if" and ends in a question mark".

Comment: It had a "Not an Answer" flag on it, which I declined.

Comment: That was my flag, because I saw it as a question and "not an answer". It was structured like a question with a question mark as I see it. Happy to understand differently if you care to explain though :)

Comment: So in reality, answers like this should not be flagged at all, but should be discouraged through down-votes?

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber: That is my take, yes.

Comment: Yet another "through the looking glass" rule to remember, along with "off topic" not really meaning "off topic", ... :-(

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: The way out of the looking glass is to ask yourself: "Does this answer have to be forcibly removed because it is actively harming the site?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes. By this site's definition of "harming". In the same way answers are removed when are a direct question, even if asking something relevant to the original question. It's very confusing for users to have a strict policy of Q&A enforced in every way, but let something through for no (apparent) reason. A question isn't an answer, rhetorical or otherwise. Since being here, I've always been led to believe by Meta answers & help section that an answer must be an "answer", nothing else, not a rhetorical question. It's confusing, & I can see why the term "looking glass" was used.

Comment: @James: But "Not an Answer" flags were never intended to remove answers (question marks notwithstanding) that directly address the question being asked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It all depends on what you call _harm_. If the answer would make new users think questions posted as answer are allowed, then I think there is a little of harm. Already is difficult to make new users understand that an answer should answer the question, not asking further details; if then there are answers that seems more questions to get more information, it becomes even harder.

Comment: So, for an answer that is "not an answer" don't use the "not an answer" flag? Surely you can see why this is confusing? What are they intended for, and why is this not in the description? (not suggesting it's anyone's fault...just trying to understand) flag desc = "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question"

Comment: @James: I've said it before, and I'll say it again.  Reserve your "Not an Answer" flags for things that make no attempt to answer the question, like "I have the same problem, has anyone found a solution," "I have a new question, how do you..." and "+1, would read again."  For everything else that you *still* think should be removed, cast a custom moderator flag, and explain why.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm obviously with James here in terms of what constitutes "harm", but note that in addition to this being another instance of an English word/phrase being used in a non-standard way, it's now another case of the usage being defended on the grounds of "but we never intended to it mean that". With all due respect to the designers, I think the language issues are really independent of original intent.

Comment: This is very simple @Peter; just use "Not an Answer" for the unambiguous cases, that's all.  Don't make the mods try and figure out what you meant when you flag an answer as "Not an Answer" when that answer clearly addresses the question being asked and is trying to be helpful (again, question marks notwithstanding).  It's all about intent, not punctuation.

Comment: @Robert I added a link to this thread below the answer. Then the Answerer updated his answer. Thanks for giving him the opportunity. The system worked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Ok it now makes sense (sincerely, and thanks) but you shouldn't have to explain it in your own words because the flag wording is misleading.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What makes life in "alternative worlds" difficult is not that any one rule is simple or not, it's that the rules are fundamentally at odds with the "real world". In the real world, questions are unambiguously not answers, off topic means off topic, closed means closed, a "real question" is a "real question", a discussion is a discussion, etc. And I respectfully disagree that "it's all about intent". When it comes to evaluating questions, it's all about what's actually _in_ the question (e.g. evidence of understanding), not what folks intended.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: I'll give an example of what I mean by intent.  When a user creates an account for the sole purpose of posting links to their blog in answers (absent any helpful contextual information) our response is generally to destroy their account, taking all of their answers with it.  We do this *even though they might technically be answering the questions,* because their intent is to promote their website, not to participate meaningfully in the question/answer process.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: I also dispute the assertion that your real world is that black and white.  Were that the case, no judgments would ever need to be made, and there would be no need for moderators at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I acknowledge that my "it's all about evidence" was hyperbole, but it was in reaction to your statement that "it's all about intent". I agree that intent ought to play a role and I agree that judgement is often required in the real world and I'm glad moderators consider the latter and exercise the former.  But I contend that's not what we're talking about here. We're talking about the systematic definition of terms/phrases to include the opposite of what they usually mean.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In particular, I think your deletion of the rogue account and it's associated questions and answers as being a great example of intent rendering the whole categorization process moot, not an example of intent justifying a (mis)categorization.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: The description for the "Not an Answer" flag says *"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."*  Did it attempt to answer the question?  Should it be an edit?  Should it be a new question? That it fits a single criteria for being Not an Answer ("it should possibly be a comment") is not what I call a good fit for the flag.

Comment: @Peter: I think it's rather ironic that a discussion sparked from disagreement over the meaning of an answer has devolved into a debate over the meaning of a flag. In both cases, it is helpful to use the context of the words in determining what they mean, or rather were intended to mean.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Again, the similarities to the rationalization for the titles "off topic" and "not a real question" are striking (i.e. referring to the sub-text). In this case, however, I think the answer clearly fit the categorization. It did not attempt to answer the question and it should definitely have been a comment.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Eh, the "off-topic" thing is a red herring.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, where we've taken great pains to explain exactly why your question might still be off-topic, even though it is programming-related.  The "off-topic" moniker is only a problem for people who can't read, especially those who can't read past the words "off-topic" to the actual close reason.

Comment: @Shog9 Actually, I think this is very much on-topic. I contend that answering a question with a question is very much "bad form" for the same reason that such answer are in fact "not an answer" (i.e. flaggable). They are responses intended to allow the questioner to answer the question for themselves, suitable for comments, but not as answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I and the others who have repeatedly said that "titles matter" are very capable of reading the explanations. Indeed, our objection to the titles is largely based on the fact that the explanations are inconsistent with the real world interpretation of those explanations.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin:  And you're certainly entitled to that opinion.  Just don't expect mods to read your mind, that's all I'm sayin'.  If an answer is genuinely harmful to the site, just say so, *using a custom flag.*

Comment: @Peter: why so?

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry, but "why so _what_"? My comment to you included three declarative sentences. Which of them where you asking "why so" about?

Comment: I don't know what you meant by the first one (I didn't say anything was off-topic), so... The last two. Why do you consider them bad form? And why are they suitable for comments? Feel free to respond by editing your answer, since it doesn't bother stating your rationale for any of this at present.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ?? I'm really confused. Flags are used for all kinds of things, such as flagging a question that doesn't meet the question criteria by users can't vote to close. Those question are only "harmful to the site" in the sense that if they remain as is, they set a bad example, etc. I assumed flagging an answer was similar.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Use a Custom flag instead of "Not an Answer" for the cases where "Not an Answer" is ambiguous, and type in a statement explaining why the answer should be deleted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm going to stop now. We seem to be going in circles. Thank you for your moderator service, though. I really mean that.

Answer (score 2):

When I see a question that is clearly, obviously, patently homework, and the person asking is just asking for someone to do their homework, I have been known to answer with a Sotocratically leading question aiming at what they need to know. There's a fine line here; I leave a comment unless I feel confident that the leading question leads very clearly indeed to the necessary thing.