# Why is this flag being declined?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

I'm a new reviewer and I would like to get some feedback.

I've flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487322/what-is-asp-net-identitys-iusersecuritystampstoretuser-interface/19499328#19499328) as **not an answer**.

My flag was declined, with the reasoning - "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it", while:

- This post asks multiple "sub questions", that wasn't even addressed.
- In the only thing it did try to answer  - he only provided a link.

Would appreciate your opinion.

Comment: This looks like one of those unfortunate cases where the new user does not have enough rep to comment so has no option but to submit their suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Actually, their other option is to wait until they have 50 rep.

Comment: When a single question contains multiple "sub-questions", I'm not sure it's unreasonable for someone to answer only one of them.

Comment: Sometimes multiple questions can be answered in a handful of sentences

Comment: @Shog9: That would be great, if one of his questions were "which tool should I use," which would be off-topic anyway.

Comment: Just sayin', as a general rule, "doesn't completely answer complicated question" isn't a good test for "not an answer". @Robert. Agree that this particular answer doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: Should be pointed out that the NAA flag has been a source of confusion for some of us for a long time, hence the feature request at [Either I need clarification on the 'Not an answer' flags or it needs a new description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180247/either-i-need-clarification-on-the-not-an-answer-flags-or-it-needs-a-new-descr?lq=1) which is unhelpfully closed as a duplicate of [How do I properly use the “it is not an answer” flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-it-is-not-an-answer-flag)...

Comment: @jball: What additional clarification needs to be provided that is not already in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-it-is-not-an-answer-flag?

Comment: @Robert, how about just having the flag [actually describe how it's intended to be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188092/142853)? I know you think it's quibbling, I've seen your comments on it elsewhere, but the fact that this keeps coming up should cause you to reconsider whether or not it is worth a little bit of time coming up with better flag text.

Comment: @jball: Have you seen [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199460) [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198207) posts?

Comment: @Robert yeah, and we obviously disagree on how things would best be done. I suppose asking that a flag text be in alignment with its usage is not only quibbling in your eyes, but some sort of failure. Not sure why. That being said, for you to ask _What additional clarification needs to be provided_ is frankly irrationally dismissive of the viewpoints that don't agree with yours.

Comment: @jball: Mostly, my disagreement is that these attempts at changing verbiage result in endless nitpicking over phrasing, the use of various words, and the proper use of **bolding,** punctuation and other grammatical pedantry.  It's terribly misguided; the amount of effort expended is beyond all proportion to the amount of potential benefit, and it's unscientific: nobody really knows what the best verbiage is, only the verbiage that sounds the best to them personally.

Comment: @jball:  This is my preferred wording, because it states specifically what we want: *Reserve your "Not an Answer" flags for things like "I have the same problem, has anyone found a solution," "I have a new question, how do you..." and "+1, would read again." For anything else that you still think should be removed, cast a custom moderator flag, and explain why.*  But nobody wants to do it this way; they want to conceptually "back into" an explanation with verbiage that nobody fully understands except the insiders, hoping to find some combination of magic words that works.

Comment: @Robert, I'd be very happy with that as the flag text over the current. Not sure if that means you'd agree that the flag text bears changing?

Comment: @jball: My wording is just one suggestion of many.

Comment: @Robert, I find your proposition of a new wording at odd with statements you have made against rewording the flag. I feel like I'm missing some parts of your position. I'm probably just being dense, but I'm confused.

Comment: If I could just put the new wording in, I would.  But I can't; we need proposals to identify the "proper" wording.  We need design by committee.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: it is in its current state because I chose to *unilaterally* edit it, mostly to quell the objections of those folks who dispute the meaning of "off-topic."  Forgive me for being blunt, but I don't have time for arguments about what the meaning of "is" is.

Comment: @Robert fair enough though I'm still confused, but if there was a place to vote for your above wording I'd support it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Use this tool to find your answer"  (or more accurately, "use this *other* tool to find your answer") is not an answer to the question that was asked, although it *is an answer.*

I deleted it.

In the future, use a custom flag, and describe exactly what the problem is.

Comment: So how should this be flagged in the future?  This is very similar to a previous question I had about [github answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199793/strategy-to-handle-answers-containing-github-links) github links are basically use this tool types of answers.

Comment: As you can see, not every moderator/reviewer has the same opinions!

Comment: @bluefeet: As always, with a custom flag, if you're not sure.  I added some clarification to my answer.

Comment: Once again a situation where [Allow anyone to comment but hide low-rep users' comments until reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186954/allow-anyone-to-comment-but-hide-low-rep-users-comments-until-reviewed) might have been useful - I can't see the deleted "answer" though so I can't judge whether that would have been ok as comment or simply added noise

Comment: The downside of custom flags is that it can take weeks until a moderator acts on it. (Do we need even more SO mods?)

Comment: This is the answer. I declined this flag for the reason that Robert points out. To go a little more in depth: The answer wasn't the issue: It addressed a question the OP had (How do I get the source code to this ASP.NET method/class?) and it provided value. The real issue is that the OP's question needed a lot of work to be a *good* answerable question. I can't fault the answerer for that. Anyone working with .NET will know that the way to get the source is to use a dissassembler or reflection tool like ILSpy, that's why it was an answer.  Long story short, Robert's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 5):

A partial answer to the question isn't "not an answer".  If you feel that the answer is sufficiently lacking then it may be a poor quality answer; poor quality answers should be downvoted, not flagged.

As for the use of a link, the answer is not "useless" without a link.  It's suggesting a product, but it also takes a bit of time to describe what the product is.  it's not *fantastic*, but it's certainly above the level at which I'd want to see it deleted.  There is information to be gained from the answer even without following the link.

The clear point here is that the post is *attempting* to answer the question.  You may not like the answer, or feel that it's lacking or doesn't solve the problem, but it's an *attempt*, so NAA doesn't apply here.

Answer (score -4):

I am also a new reviewer, but I would say that is an answer, although a poor one.  It does not thoroughly answer the question, but it does at least offer a little bit of help.

Deleting an answer is a bold thing to do.  It is saying, *no thanks, your answer is not welcome here*.  In cases like this, it is probably best to leave the answer there, but not give it any upvotes.

An answer that must be deleted would be something like:

> yeah, I don't know either, good luck lol

Comment: Actually, if you read the help section on answering "a little bit of help" is not classified as an answer. That is was comments are for.